# init file upload with information from session

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, web, dropzone.js

How can I implement the following scenario:

1. on page A I have a form with a file upload and I select a few files to upload
2. then I click Next which submits the form and I upload the files to the controller and save them in a session and redirect to the page B.
3. on page B I press Back and want to display the files that I uploaded previously with the ability to delete them or add new ones.

Can you pls tell if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Although the information you have provided is woefully insufficient, I will try and answer you the best I can. You will need to have a directory for temporarily storing files. I imagine that because you have a "Back" and "Next" button that this is a part of a process where the user is required to fulfil the requirements of multiple steps before completing.

You will need to store the files in some type of temporary directory, and then store where those files are in a session or cookie. Once the user has completed the process, you will need to retrieve that information from the session or cookie, move the files to the appropriate directory and then remove them from temp.

You might need a regular cron job or equivalent to remove any temp files that are left over.